# Precisely how does Rammus's movespeed boost (powerball) work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Rammus goes faster during Powerball. Unlike almost every other ability in the game, the tooltip for Powerball doesn't specify how much of a speed increase Rammus receives. Mobafire, Leaguecraft, and SoloMid don't appear to have specifics available, either.

Does the ability in general increase your movement speed by a percentage, or a flat amount?

Is there any credence to the hearsay I've encountered which indicates that powerball ignores the soft caps on movespeed?

Answer (score 5):

Rammus' powerball appears to be a % speed increase, reportedly increasing about 10% of his movement speed per second.

This means a Rammus with 5 phantom dancers will have a significantly faster powerball than a Rammus with just boots.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_speed

The reason Rammus appears to avoid the soft caps on movement speed is because Powerball compounds his movement speed - it's being reduced by the caps, but it's still a significant enough amount that it *does* increase, which means the next application of Powerball's "speedup" tick will apply more than the previous, even *with* the soft cap.

These can combine to push Rammus' speed into egregious territories.

Comment: Cool! Let me make sure I understand correctly...

So for 1 second at the end of powerball, he gets an 80% bonus to his total movespeed, which means that something like zeal would not be terribly noticable during Powerball, but flat increases (such as the highest-speed boots) can produce a more extreme effect on him than on other champions.

Also, does ranking up the ability increase the speed numbers at all?

Comment: @Gumbz - No, it means each second, Rammus' current movespeed *= 1.10 (and then diminishing returns are applied). It doesn't matter **how** Rammus' speed is increased, just that it's used as the basis for powerball numbers.

Comment: So it's not 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc up to 1.8 over 8 seconds, it's actually an exponential 1.1, 1.21... up to 2.143 at the very end? That would match several places where I've seen it said that the 8th second is "about a 100% increase to speed".

Comment: @Gumbz - As best as I can determine, yes.